# Facial expressions identification like snapchat

Tags: android, face-detection, face-recognition

I am working on app that detect eye blink of the user. I have been searching the web for 2 days but still don't have clear vision about how this can be done.

As far as i have knew is that the system supports face detection which is detecting if there is a face in the picture and locating it.

But this works only with images and detect only faces which is not what i need. I need to open an camera activity and directly detect the face of the user and locate his eyes and other facial parts and wait till he blinks, like when you long click on the screen on snap chat.

I have seen a lot about `open-cv` but still not sure what it is or how to use it or if it seize my goals.

Note: snap chat has no API released for the technology used, and even it doesn't let anyone to talk to the engineers behind this technology.

Comment: I don't see any questions in your post... Anyways, please keep in mind that "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library, tutorial** or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow".

Comment: @ElouarnLaine i stated what i want in this sentence (I need to open an camera activity and directly detect the face of the user and locate his eyes and other facial parts and wait till he blinks) and am asking what is correct way to do this, which is not off-topic

Comment: then what you are asking is **way** too broad. I'd recommend you to learn OpenCV and go through [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html). Eventually you will find a way to detect blinks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that openCV has the ability to allow image processing on the device's camera feed (as opposed to only being able to process still images).

Here is an introductory tutorial on eye detection using openCV:
http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/

If you can't find eye-blink detection tutorials in a google search, I think you'll have to create the code for eye-blink detection on your own, but I think openCV will be a helpful tool in doing so. There are lots of beginner openCV tutorials to help you get started.

Comment: thank you for your help, but already i saw this tutorial and read the code. but still not very helpful

Comment: There is a google vision api (apparently) that can detect blinks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586490/detect-eye-blink-using-google-vision-api

I would suggest googling "blink detection android app". From what I gather, it's not a simple feat to detect blinks.